# Why is can't I see event action in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

This morning I used google tag manager to collect clicks on the product pages of this website, e.g. www.lptent.co.uk/products/co. The buttons that I really want to track are "Configure my Gazebo" and "Generate quote" but I can't see them in analytics' Event Action column.

I am using the {{element id}} for the Event Action in tag manager and I can see other IDs that have been clicked in analytics. I have also checked that the tag fires when I click these buttons but I still can't see them. The domain of the website does change when these buttons are clicked so maybe that could have something to do with it?

Help appreciated!

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on this recently and was hoping to get things working automatically in GTM. I didn't quite work out that way so I've been pushing the Event to the dataLayer and picking it up from there. This page has all the information I needed to create the events and set up GTM to pick them up from the dataLayer

https://www.distilled.net/blog/getting-started-with-google-tag-manager/

I tried using the jquery `$('elementID').click()` handler to do this but although it worked fine in testing it didn't when I rolled it out.

```
$( "#ElementID" ).click(function() {
dataLayer.push({'event': 'trackEvent', 'gtmCategory': 'myCategory', 'gtmAction': 'Click', 'gtmLabel': 'LinkName'}); });
```

Instead I just used

```
onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'trackEvent', 'gtmCategory': 'myCategory', 'gtmAction': 'Click', 'gtmLabel': 'LinkName'});"
```

to fire the event and this seems to work with both links and Form Submit buttons. Strangely the `jquery $('ElementID).load` works fine (there is a good reason for that!)

I know it's not quite as elegant as GTM seems to promise but it does seem to work.